# How can I empty the trash can in JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, recycle-bin

I have a Pro JFrog Cloud account and I can't empty my Trash Can. (It contains 1.32GB data.) I tried to follow [this](https://www.devopszones.com/2020/07/how-to-delete-trash-can-in-jfrog.html) article, but I can't find the
"Trash Can settings" above Look & Feel Settings. Is it removed from the UI?

I also can't find [Usage statistics](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-see-my-artifactory-online-disk-usage-transfer-usage-and-transfer-rate/) on my Admin page although I am admin. I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: I tried to use the REST API to list the content of Trash can ("api/storage/auto-trashcan"), I got "301 Moved permanently" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are a cloud customer, I assume you are version 7.x, while the document you shared is of Artifactory 6.x, and hence looks different than your instance.

The same should be found under **Administrtaion->(Services)Artifactory->General->Settings**, and then scroll to the bottom. There, you will be able to enable/disable trash can, set its retention period, and empty the trash can.

Additionally, you should be able to right click on the Trash Can in **Application->Artifacts** and "Empty Trash Can".

Note that you may also use the "Empty Trash Can" command using REST API, which is:

> curl -XPOST -u user:password https://SERVER-NAME>.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/trash/empty

Comment: Thanks. Especially for pointing out the version difference between the JFrog cloud and the referenced docs.